# Resize image or load thumbnail

Tags: html, load, resize, double

The image system on the server i am working on has multiple sizes of every image, which i can all use. How would i go if i needed the same image, in different sizes, on one page twice? (for example: in a simple image gallery, that has all images loaded at the same time, but has only one large version and three thumbnails visible.)

Would i load the larger and smaller images both from the server, or would i load the larger, and size it with css to make the smaller version?

Thanks for your insights.

Comment: Your question title doesn't appear to bear much relation to the actual question.  Don't resize the big image, use the thumbnails and preload your big images in the background, either with JavaScript or CSS.

Comment: The point is, however, the image's don't need to be preloaded, they already are. They are just not _in sight..._

Answer (score 0):

display the smaller ones in the gallery, then on click or whatever, load the larger version.

Comment: The larger versions, as well as the smaller ones, will both(!) be loaded, all(!) at the same time. In that case, is it wiser to load two images or resize one?

Comment: The preview is just for overview of the current location in the list. So basicly, the question is: What is best for the user experience? Loading a new image (and thus using more bandwidth), or resizing?

Answer (score -1):

I understand that question is:

What is better publish a thumbnail of a large image? or resize the large image with css simulating a thumbnail?

I suppose it is publishing a thumbnail and not resizing the large image.